# Forkless upgrade from v0.9.16 to v0.9.17 fails

Tags: runtime-upgrade, upgrade

I am working on a Substrate node update.

I have a [node from Substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node) that runs on [v0.9.16](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.16). When I am executing forkless upgrade to [v0.9.17](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.17) via [polkadot apps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer) (v0.121.2-89-x) it fails and I can see a transaction status in browser console `"status":{"invalid":null}`. I receive the same error if I execute the upgrade programmatically via polkadot/api (v7.15.2-15).

I’ve checked the node’s logs with debug log level and did not find related errors or warnings.

If I run the [v0.9.17](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.17) node in `--dev` mode it works as expected.

I’ve tried to skip [v0.9.17](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.17) and update to [v0.9.18](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.18) and received `1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits`. To avoid this error I’ve tried to use [sudo.sudoUncheckedWeight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65932003/1694083) but the result is the same.

Any ideas how can I:

1. Identify an issue of invalid status during forkless upgrade execution?
2. Avoid `1010` error?

Comment: To be clear: are you using an unmodified node? It is possible that a migration was not implemented would be my first guess if so, as the node itself isn't meant to be used seamlessly in production in the way you are trying to upgrade.

Comment: The case I've described reproduces on unmodified [node from the Substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node). All migrations should be there, right?

Comment: Runtime wasm file size is more than 5 MB. Can it be an issue?

Comment: Make sure you are using the `compressed` wasm.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. It helps. I was using `compact` one.